# Bootstrap affix sidebar issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar, affix

I have a problem with my website project. I want to make affix with my #sidebar, based on: [this](http://www.bootply.com/73864) tutorial, but it's still not working...

What's wrong ?

website xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't the `<header>` tag, try to put the first part of the page into it.

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('header').height()
    }
});
```

This code read the height of the `<header>` container and start the affix at that height.
In alternative, you can put the header in a div with class or id and use `$('.headerclass').height()` or `$('#headerid').height()`.

Comment: Right, but after add <header> tag, this is what happend [click](http://rmitula.pl/project/now.php) [1]: http://rmitula.pl/project/now.php